# Explanation of “tkt” and what contexts it can be used in

Tags: sens, argot, langage-des-jeunes, sms-lingo

I lived near Bergerac for a few years, but didn't really use Facebook to connect with my French friends until I left the country really.

I often see *tkt* used, but I cannot figure out the context, or really what it means. A friend expanded it for me a while ago but it was not clear to me why he was using it in that sentence.

If somebody could expand it, translate it and use it in a few contexts, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*tkt* is SMS lingo for *t'inquiète*, shortened form of *ne t'inquiète pas*. It has the same usage as *don't worry* or *that is all right* in English.

> — *Désolé pour hier soir*
> — *T'inquiète*
>
> — Sorry for last night
> — Don't worry, that's all right

And, recently, I believe, it has started to be used to emphasize an affirmation

> — *Oh, t'as la classe, ce soir*
> — *T'inquiète, bien sûr que j'ai la classe*
>
> — Wow, you're classy, tonight
> — You bet your ass I am¹

but this usage still sounds very *banlieusard*.

---

¹ Fell free to correct my attempts at American English slang.

Comment: Merci, c'est la réponse exacte que je voulais.

Comment: That's definitely American English and not British English slang haha

Comment: @MartinMulvey What would it be in British English?

Comment: @evpok "you bet your arse"? >_>;;

Comment: It would depend which part of the country you were from. I would say something like "obviously." In that context.

Answer (score 3):

This is precisely the same thing English people tend to use some time that is *np* for *No Problem*.